# detect a single ball out of two (Python)

Tags: python

So i've got an image in input an i transformed it into an array. There is two ball, and i want to remove one ball.
My idea is to run through a loop, and detect line by line if there is a red pixel. And if in this array at an i, and there is not red pixel in i+1 it erase the entire rest of the line.

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    h = h + 1
    #print("0"),
    if (i>1) and (((data[i - 1])[1] > 40  and (data[i - 1])[2] > 40 ) and ((data[i + 1])[1] > 40 and (data[i+1])[2])):
           print("_"),
    elif  (data[i])[1] < 40 and (data[i])[2] < 40 and (data[i])[0] > 50  :
               j = j + 1
               print "#" ,
    else :
                   print("."),
               #else : 
       # print data[i],


    if h == 64 :
       h = 0
       test = True

       print("\n")
```

What is wrong with my code and how can i erase a ball through my method ?

Comment: Ok. You didn't ask a question though so...

Comment: Maybe you could not render the red in the first place in that condition? Or render a new frame without it?

Comment: Are you doing collision detection?

Comment: I'm not doing a collision detection, i think.. But I'm doing a "red ball recognition" and i want to be able to detect just one ball.

Comment: Are these real/photorealistic images? How are they generated? What's in the background? Is there noise?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete anything on the left side:

```
data[:,:data.shape[1]/2] = 0
```

or right side:

```
data[:,data.shape[1]/2:] = 0
```

If your problem is that you have balls (red, green and blue) in an array (numpy) and there's no background or noise. For simplicity, if the color of red = 1, green = 2 and blue = 3 then:

```
data[np.where(data == 1)] = 0
```

will remove the red ball. For more sophisticated detection-needs you can use below...

You can use label from scipy.ndimage given that your data is an np-array by simply saying (of course if your balls get too overlapped they may not be separated):

```
from scipy.ndimage import label
labled_data, labels = label(data)
#If you want to remove the first ball
labled_data[np.where(labled_data == 1)] = 0
#Then your second ball will be where the labled data is 2
#Else if you just temporary want to know where the second ball is:
labled_data == 2
#Will be true for those places
```

Comment: even if my array is just composed of 3 variables, Red, Green and Blue ?

Comment: Don't quite get you here, I thought you had an array (data) with balls that you want to detect. If you mean that you just have an array and the pixels where the red ball is the only place where red is and you want to remove all red then there are easier ways.

Comment: It's almost like that. If i have two balls in the array, one in the left, and one in the right, i want to delete the one on the right.

Comment: If they have different colors you can still use that code, but if you just want to remove everything on the left side...I'll update...